# Programming Percentages in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, division

--56/25000*100 = 0.244 = 0.2 % as percentage column answer

I am trying to write out this math problem as a query in pl/sql.
The table looks like this

Test_Name , Total# Pass, Fail, Percent, View_name

I need to write out a query that divides the total number of records that fail (56) against the total number of records with in the table (25000) times 100.

How can this be queried?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this

```
select 100.0 * count(case when fail = true then 1 else null end) / count(*) 
from table_name;
```